# Flask Mysql Connector issue

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Making a simple login/register app on flask and I have encountered this issue?

What am I doing wrong here? The register Form works perfectly. The login section doesn't work
How can I fix it. 
I have to do this in order to replace flask-mysqldb with the mysql.connector for python

I get this error on login submit:

mysql.connector.errors.InternalError

mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

creating a new connection to the dB for the login, gives me this error

builtins.TypeError

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

app.py is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key='secretkey'


#Config MySQL
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='jay', password='jay',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='usertable')
#cnx.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [validators.Length(min=1, max=50)])
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=50)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords do not match')
        ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')



@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))
        #connect to db
        #create Cursor
        cur = cnx.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
        #commit 2 DB
        cnx.commit()
        #close connection
        cur.close()
        cnx.close()
        flash('You are now registered and can log in', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('login'))


    return render_template('register.html', form=form)


#USER login CONFIGURaTION
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #get form fields
        username = request.form['username']
        password_candidate = request.form['password']
        #connect to db
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='jay', database='table_users')
        #cursor creation
        cur = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True, buffering=True)
        #get user by username
        result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users Where username = %s", [username])

        if cur:
            #get stored hash
            data = cur.fetchone()

            password = data['password']
            #compare passwords
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, password):
                app.logger.info('Password MATCHED')
            else:
                app.logger.info('Password not MATCHED')
        else:
            app.logger.info('No USER')
        cur.close()
        cnx.close()


    return render_template('signin.html')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: please include the full traceback.. have you tried running `result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", username)` without the brackets? otherwise, try printing `result` to the console

Comment: As for the unread result error, try changing `cur = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)` to `cur = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)`

Comment: indeed result returns nothing to the console, only the next line :data = cur.fetchone()" returns the whole record as a dict.

Comment: Ah, that's the thing. An execute query does *not* return anything. It's the cursor object itself. Delete the `result = ` part. Then you could change `if result > 0` to `if cur` (should be a NoneType if no match in the username is found). Might be wrong though but just a guess

Comment: I am assuming the problem might be somewhere in the connection I set up. Where should I close connection after registerForm and start connection again for the /login? I think this is the issue somehow. This is the first time I'm using mysql.connector.

Comment: Without result part and changd to if cur >  0, I get the following error : builtins.TypeError

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MySQLCursorBufferedDict' and 'int'

Comment: Ah okay. I'm rather unfamiliar with how mysql.connector works too. Btw, in above I meant `if cur:` not `if cur > 0:`, sorry for that!

Comment: SOLVED. cursor.close() and creating a new connection solved the problem. Thank @mangohero1

Comment: glad I could help! Best of luck. feel free to self-answer and I will gladly upvote it

Comment: Everything works just fine except the last if (app.logger.info('No USER')) now presents the following error : builtins.TypeError

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: that's strange, nothing syntactic that would immediately give it away. i suppose it could be a choppy connection?

Answer (score 0):

don't need to close connection and reopen, you can use this instead:

```
your_database.get_conn()
```